# How to handle nested arrays / return more than one array using Snapshot

Tags: angular, observable

I have the below code as market.mode.ts

```js
export class Market{
    srdCat: any; 
}
```

and the below as a service in Angular Application.

```js
private srds: Market[] = [{
    srdCat: [{
        tier: "one",
        details: [{
            srdName: "1",
            srdLink: "Tier 1 Value 1"
        },
        {
            srdName: "2",
            srdLink: "Tier 1 Value 2"
        }]
    }, {
        tier: "two",
        details: [{
            srdName: "3",
            srdLink: "Tier 2 Value 1"
        },
        {
            srdName: "4",
            srdLink: "Tier 2 Value 2"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I am trying to capture the tier from URL to display the array details. Like, If I pass /one in the URL, i need all the items in details : [] array

In my Oninit() I have the below code

```
const srdCat = this._route.snapshot.params['srdCat.tier'];
this.srds = this._test.getSRD(srdCat.tier);
console.log(this.srds);
```

I get the below error at this.srds

> Type 'Market' is missing the following properties from type 'Market[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2740)

Could someone help me with the code in fetching the array? Is it possible with Snapshot or I need to try only with Observable.

Comment: What is Marketplace? unable to recreate the issue with the information that you shared; kindly check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oafr6j

Comment: @AkberIqbal Hey It;s Market. I am trying to capture the tier value (/one) from URL and to display the details array.

Comment: The error comes from a line of code you didn't post, and which tries to use a variable of type Market where a value of type Market[], i.e. array of Market, is needed.

Comment: @JBNizet In ngOninit,   srds : Market;  I tried to make it as in array, if I do that, the error points to this.srds  = this._test.getSRD(srdCat.tier)